# How to solve no signature of method with groovy in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi line script

```
sh """
        SCRIPT_BRANCH=${SCRIPT_BRANCH:-develop}
        curl -o ${LIQUIBASE_CI_SCRIPT} -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN}" --header ${SCRIPT_BRANCH}/src/shell/branch_cut_liquibase_gen.sh
        chmod +x ${LIQUIBASE_CI_SCRIPT}
        curl -o ${LIQUIBASE_GEN_SCRIPT} -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN}" --header ${SCRIPT_BRANCH}/src/shell/liquibase_generation.sh
        chmod +x ${LIQUIBASE_GEN_SCRIPT}
        curl -o ${LIQUIBASE_TRANSFORM_SCRIPT} ${SCRIPT_BRANCH}/src/python/liquibase_transform.py
        chmod +x ${LIQUIBASE_TRANSFORM_SCRIPT} 
        ${LIQUIBASE_CI_SCRIPT}
    """.stripMargin()

    email(${EMAIL}, ${DEFAULT_CONTENT})

def build = bareBuild() {
    buildAction = branchCutAction
}
```

like so within my groovy file. It's being called by jenkins and I am getting this error.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.negative() is applicable for argument types: () values: []Possible solutions: notify(), normalize(), next()
```

I'm really at a loss as to why this can be the case. I've looked through similar questions and nothing seems to match up with my issue

Comment: Could you edit title of your question to make it more aesthetic? Pasting errors there is bad habit on SO

Comment: sure edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `stripMargin()` previous to `sh`, thus separate them into two code block.

```
def cmd = """
        SCRIPT_BRANCH=${SCRIPT_BRANCH:-develop}
        curl -o ${LIQUIBASE_CI_SCRIPT} -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN}" --header ${SCRIPT_BRANCH}/src/shell/branch_cut_liquibase_gen.sh
        chmod +x ${LIQUIBASE_CI_SCRIPT}
        curl -o ${LIQUIBASE_GEN_SCRIPT} -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN}" --header ${SCRIPT_BRANCH}/src/shell/liquibase_generation.sh
        chmod +x ${LIQUIBASE_GEN_SCRIPT}
        curl -o ${LIQUIBASE_TRANSFORM_SCRIPT} ${SCRIPT_BRANCH}/src/python/liquibase_transform.py
        chmod +x ${LIQUIBASE_TRANSFORM_SCRIPT} 
        ${LIQUIBASE_CI_SCRIPT}
    """

sh "${cmd}"

email("${EMAIL}", "${DEFAULT_CONTENT}")
```

Comment: I didn't have .stripMargin() before, and it still wasn't working. What issue does the code you wrote fix that changes in both cases?

Comment: If so ,the error comes from `email(${EMAIL}, ${DEFAULT_CONTENT})`

Comment: why though? What do you think the issue is?

Comment: For this parttern `${EMAIL}` , it's used in bash or Groovy GString.  When used in bash means `EMAIL` is an environment or bash variable.  When used as Groovy GString, you need to wrapper it by double quote.   Using `${EMAIL}` directly without in `sh` or  wrapped by `"` is wrong.    If wrong not comes from it, the last wrong place is the code block: `def build = bareBuild() {....}`